# combine specific output and display in specific header

Tags: awk

I am trying to combine all matching text before the left of the `|` and output that to the column "Gene". The amount of lines in the match are outputted to the "Targets" column, the average of `$3`  to the "Average Depth" column, along with the average of the #'s to the right of the `=` to the " Average GC" column. I am having some trouble in doing this and need some expert help. Thank you :).

**input**

```
chr10:79793602-79793721 RPS24|gc=59.7 150.3
chr10:79795083-79795202 RPS24|gc=41.2 111.4
chr10:79797665-79797784 RPS24|gc=37 69.8
chr11:119077113-119077232 CBL|gc=67.9 27.3
chr11:119103143-119103420 CBL|gc=41.9 240.3
chr11:119142430-119142606 CBL|gc=42.6 177.1
chr11:119144563-119144749 CBL|gc=46.2 324.4
```

**current output**

```
Gene     TargetsAverage DepthAverage GC
gc           803     0.0     0.0
```

**desired output**

```
ID         times          depth         GC
RPS24        3            110.5         46.0
CBL          4            192.3         49.7
```

**awk**

```
awk -F'[ |=]' '
{
id[$2] += $4
value[$2] += $5
occur[$2]++
}
END{
printf "%-8s%8s%8s%8s\n", "Gene", "Targets", "Average Depth", "Average GC"
for (i in id)       
printf "%-8s%8d%8.1f%8.1f\n", i, occur[i],value[i]/occur[i],id[i]/occur[i]
}' input
```

Comment: What trouble are you having?

Comment: This looks close. Add your current output. Good luck.

Comment: I added the current output as it is not what I expected.  Thank you :).

Comment: your desired output header doesn't match the `printf ... Gene` that creates your current header. First column, Gene or ID? Good luck.

Comment: learn to add debugging output, like `print "#dbg: $2=" $2` I think you'll see your problem then. Good luck.

Comment: It appears that `$2` is `gc` and not either `RPS24` or `CBL` as you want.  That means you need to analyze how the FS is set.  You can debug/confirm this by printing `$1` and `$2` with appropriate tags (`print "1 = [", $1, "], 2 = [", $2, "]"` in the 'every line' processing).  However, when I run the script verbatim from the question on Mac OS X 10.10.5 (both BSD Awk and GNU Awk), it gives me the desired output.

Answer (score 1):

@Chris - Your editing of the question has not been very helpful, but I can confirm that, except for the first printf statement, the program runs as expected, which is in accordance with the "desired output". I have used three different `awk`s; the only difference between the outputs is (as expected) the ordering of the rows.  You may have to be more specific about the version of awk you are using.

Comment: Agreed: I only tried two versions of Awk (GNU Awk 4.1.3 and BSD Awk 'awk version 20070501') on Mac OS X 10.10.5, but both produce the expected numeric output.  The question should be closed 'cannot reproduce' unless we get more information from the OP.  Would you care to identify the versions of Awk you tested, and the platform(s) on which you did the testing?

Comment: Make that four: On a Linux machine: GNU Awk 3.1.7; 
On a Mac OS: GNU Awk 4.1.3, API: 1.1; awk version 20070501;
mawk 1.3.4 20141027

Comment: I will look into it more Monday... thank you all and happy holidays :).

Answer (score 1):

Solution in [TXR](http://nongnu.org/txr):

```
$ txr table2.txr data
ID        times          depth         GC
RPS24       3            110.5         46.0
CBL         4            192.3         49.7
```

Code in `table2.txr`:

```
@(output)
ID        times          depth         GC
@(end)
@(repeat)
@  (all)
@nil:@nil-@nil @id|@nil
@  (and)
@    (collect :gap 0)
@nil:@nil-@nil @id|gc=@gc @dep
@    (set (gc dep) (@(tofloat gc) @(tofloat dep)))
@    (end)
@    (bind n @(length gc))
@    (bind avg-gc @(format nil "~,1f"
                           (/ [reduce-left + gc] n)))
@    (bind avg-dep @(format nil "~,1f"
                            (/ [reduce-left + dep] n)))
@    (output)
@{id   9}   @{n 6}       @{avg-dep 13} @{avg-gc}
@    (end)
@  (end)
@(end)
```

What lumps together the entries with the same ID is the two parallel branches of the `all` directive. The first branch loosely matches the pattern of a single line, extracting the ID, binding it to the `id` variable. This variable is visible to the second branch, where its appearance introduces a back-referencing constraint. Here, multiple consecutive (`:gap 0`) lines are matched at the same position (thus including the one which was matched in the first branch of the `all`). Only lines with the matching `id` are processed; the `collect` ends when a non-matching `id` is encountered (due to the `:gap 0` constraint) or when the input ends.